# Correlation test for a discrete independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

Right now, I am working on the comparison of two different calculation algorithms for computing the dose deposition on a patient during a radiotherapy treatment. More specifically, I am trying to evaluate if the difference $\Delta y$ on a dose coverage parameter computed with the two algorithms is correlated with the composition of the target tumour, which can be either completely solid, completely semisolid or have a solid kernel surrounded by a semisolid shell. Let $x$ be the ratio between semisolid and solid tissue in a lesion, such that $x = 0$ if the tumour is completely solid and $x = 1$ if it is completely semisolid. The dataset to analyse has been generated by discretizing the $x$ variable in 5 different points $\{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1\}$ and simulating dose depositions for different tumor sizes with this $x$ ratios. If we represent the data obtained in a boxplot, we get something like this:

[image]

It seems that if the independent variable $x$ increases, then the observed differences between the two algorithms should decrease (this has theoretical sense in this context). My question is: what statistical test could I use to check if there is a relevant correlation between the two variables? Is a log-rank test a good approximation to the problem?